# php json rpc server method can be null?

Tags: json, rpc, json-rpc

According to the JSON-RPC 2.0 specs (http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) the request method parameter should be a string. Would it be valid behavior when using .htaccess rewrite to pass the function and/or class in the url, and leave the method parameter null? The target for the service would carry the function and/or class like http://domain.com/rpc/server/class/method? which would be rewritten to a GET parameter with the name method.

Would this make sense? I haven't found a really good example how to deal with class methods in JSON-RPC requests - right now they are passed as "method": "class.method" as it seems to be the most appropriate way to do it I believe.

I'm asking this because I'm writing my own server...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great idea, in my opinion.  An advantage of JSON-RPC is being transport-agnostic so that you can use exactly the same messages whether you're using UNIX sockets, operating in the same process or riding on top of HTTP.  Your proposal strips that advantage away by relying on the URI to supply the method so that your implementation only works if you're using HTTP.  GET requests with URL-encoded parameters are somewhat awkward with JSON-RPC; I think keeping everything in POST requests is a better idea.

That said, it is your own server so you can do whatever makes sense in your use case but if you ever need standards-based clients to interoperate it's better to stay as close to the standard as possible.

For class methods `"method" : "class.method"` is what has always made sense to me.